# backbone.js take different action based on result of ajax request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone app that reads an svn file path from a url and then "ls"'s the path it's given. Normally, it just enumerates the results of the ls in a table. But what I want to do is check if the path actually corresponds to only a particular file, and in that case, fetch and display the file's contents instead.

What would be a good backbone idiomatic way of doing this? Right now in the parse function for what I've called a Directory model, I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
  parse: function(response, options) {
    if (response.length == 1 && response[0].type == "file") {
      // what to do here?
    }
    this.get('entries').reset(response);
    $("#indicator").hide();
    $('#directory-contents').show();
    this.trigger('change');
    return {};
  },
```

So I'm tempted to just kind of make an ajax request to get the file contents here (ie, at `// what to do here?`), but a) directly making an ajax request myself seems not so great, and b) I feel like I'm mixing together two models into one. Now my DirectoryView is going to probably have to check for some kind of flag to tell if it's actually rendering a directory, or just one particular file.

Any ideas on a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, after reviewing the comments and understanding your domain a bit more, I would suggest the following approach:

- Create a FSEntry model that represents a filesystem node (inode if you will). The key thing is in can represent either a directory or file
- FSEntry should have a `type` string attribute that can be 'directory', 'file', 'symlink', etc
- The basic fsEntry.fetch() should just load the metadata, including the `type` field.
- The view rendering it can render in response to model events. Based on the model instance's `type`, render appropriately (or swap in a different template for the body of the view if you like)
- If the `type` is 'file', have the view call fsEntry.fetchContent() and respond to the corresponding `change:content` event to render the file content
- You can later add logic to the model to cache the `content` data and not refetch it if you have fresh data in the cache, but that's an optimization you should add only after all the functionality is correct.

Side note based on your code sample: Do not manipulate the DOM in Model or Collection code! This is MV* facepalm failure.

Comment: I wasn't planning on manipulating the DOM in the model, but I'm going to have to make a separate ajax request if I want the file's actual contents. Is there anything better I could be doing than just having a `$.ajax(...)` in the `parse` function above?

Comment: Well, you can set up an event handler such that when a `change:type` event handles, if the file content isn't already loaded, you fetch it at that point. You could also just make a separate `loadContent` method that your view can call.

Comment: The way I think of it is you have an FSEntry with 2 sets of data: metadata and file contents. Follow the backbone pattern where `fetch` gets the metadata and make another `fetchContent` method that loads the content. I don't like the idea of the model auto-fetching the content once the metadata arrives, although you could do that. I'd rather have a controller or view tell the model to fetch the content.